# Best way of handling views

Tags: c#, visual-studio, view

I want to start that new project with the best practice possible. I have a lot of tables that are linked together. Example:

```
Person
- ID
- FirstName
- LastName

User
- ID
- PersonID
- AddressID

Address
- ID
- Line1
- Line2
```

Obviously, I will have to use a `UserView` view to be efficient in the application. The view will bring these three tables together.

Now, when someone makes a change to a user, I will have to query all three tables individually, make the changes and then update.

```
private void updateUser(UserView userView)
{
   using (var context = getNewContext()
   {
      var person = context.Person.first(c => c.ID == userView.PersonID)
      person.FirstName = userView.FirstName;
      person.LastName = userView.LastName;
      context.SaveChanges();

      var user = context.User.first(c => c.ID == userView.UserID)
      //and so on for the 3 tables
   }
}
```

There has to be a more efficient way of updating the tables! Do you know any trick?

Comment: None, a DLL in this case. Winform in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the entity framework. If you've got navigation properties you can eagerly load your object graph in one trip to the database, update the fields and then save it.

```
var user = context.User.Include("Person").Include("Address").First(c => c.ID == userView.UserID);
user.Person.FirstName = userView.FirstName;
user.Person.LastName = userView.LastName;
user.Address... // etc.
```

If you're using Linq2Sql, you've got to use DataLoadOptions. There's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx) explaining the difference between EF and Linq2Sql.

Comment: Sounds like a good alternative to views! Thanks for that suggestion!